# XML creation issues with property in tag

Tags: xml

I am facing issues in creation of xml.I am trying to create a tag like this:

```
<Stack name="LIVE" SPlevel="XXX">
```

but i am getting the output as:

```
<Stack SPlevel="XXX" name="LIVE">
```

i.e. irrespectve of the order SPlevel comes as first property of the tag.I am unable to find out the reason why it's behaving so strangely.
**I want this in the same order as the same xml is used by other scripts in the same order and i am trying to read the values of properties from a text file and creating  an xml file in notepad.

Even if i write the same line in notepad and save the file with .xml still the order is reversed when i open the file in explorer.**

Comment: What language / tool are you using to create the xml?

Comment: From XML point of view, the order of attributes doesn't matter.

Comment: First tell us ..how your generating that XMl ..using Which tool or Program (like JaxB )

Answer (score 0):

First off - the thing you need to understand is that XML doesn't care about certain things - some things are part of the document structure, and others aren't. Attribute order is one of these things. Every XML parser should handle both your cases *identically* because that's how XML is supposed to work.

If they don't, then they're broken, and trying to bodge your XML to fit a broken parser is an exercise in pain and futility.

If you're creating your plain text XML and an XML parser is reshuffing the elements - then that's not your problem, nor is it something you can do anything about.